How can I custom week header using react-native-calendars package?
Description
Problem: not show all week text content
Expected Behavior
Show all week text content and can custom week header text and its styles
Observed Behavior
Not show all week text content
Environment
-- version:
"react-native-calendars": "^1.1304.1"
(https://i.sstatic.net/XWE6G7Vc.jpg)

After digging through the code of react-native-calendars, I found out that you can use textDayHeaderFontSize in theme prop of Calendar to set the font size so it fits. See Source Code Here
If you want more control you can use 'stylesheet.calendar.header'.dayHeader See my comment here in their official repo
For even more control you can use customHeader prop which expects a compatible  React Component. See Source Code Here
